# HTML helps checkboxfor not passing the data to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have been trying to pass data to the controller from the form but it gives me null values. I have my model/controller and view as below. I even tried to use Form Collection but why is this not binding the data properly?

> Role.cs

```
 public partial class Role
    {
        public int Role_Id { get; set; }
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Door_Unlock { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Accounts { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Bounds_Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Salary_Privilege { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Card_Acceptance { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsAdmin { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller is;

> RoleController:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EmpID,Door_Unlock,Accounts,Bounds_Email,Salary_Privilege,Card_Acceptance,IsAdmin")] Role roles)
        {
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    //db.Roles.Add(roles);
                   // db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
```

> Create.cshtml

```
@model xxxxx.Models.Role

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@*@using (Html.BeginForm())*@
<form method="POST">


    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName, "Select Employee", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EnrollNumber", null, "-Select Employee-", htmlAttributes: new { id = "ddEnrollNumber", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Accounts, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor( model => model.Accounts.Value, new { name = "accountsCheck", @class = "accountsCheck", @checked = "checked" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Accounts, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bounds_Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Bounds_Email.Value, new { @class = "boundsCheck", @checked = "checked" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bounds_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Card_Acceptance, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Card_Acceptance.Value, new { @class = "cardCheck", @checked = "checked" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Card_Acceptance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Door_Unlock, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Door_Unlock.Value, new { @class = "doorUnlockCheck", @checked = "checked" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Door_Unlock, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary_Privilege, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Salary_Privilege.Value, new { @class = "salaryCheck", @checked = "checked" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salary_Privilege, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsAdmin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsAdmin.Value, new { @class = "isAdminCheck", @checked = "checked" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsAdmin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Grant Permissions" class="btn green" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>


<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn green">  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @style = "color:#FFFFFF;" }) <span class=""></span></button>

</div>


            return View();


    }
```

I even tried to use Request.Form[] method but I cannot understand why is this not binding the data properly and passing to the controller? `roles` in the controller param is always null.

Comment: You cannot use `CheckBoxFor()` on a `bool?` (you are binding to a proeprty named `Accounts.Value` which does not exist). You need to either make the property `bool` or use `EditorFor()` (which will create a dropdownlist with 3 values for `null`, `true` and `false`

Comment: And as a side note, you NEVER set the `checked` attribute when using the `CheckBoxFor()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke `You need to either make the property bool or use EditorFor() (which will create a dropdownlist with 3 values for null, true and false` it is already bool, no? plus I even tried to use editfor() `   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Accounts.Value)` no luck

Comment: okay unchecked. but the problem persists.

Comment: Its `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Account)`

Comment: still `null` is being shown

Comment: That would be because you have not selected an option :) - the code will generate a `<select>` with 3 values - 'Not Set', 'True' and 'False'

Comment: And if you want a checkbox, then you must make the property `bool` (not nullable)

Comment: Can you please give an elaborated answer? I want to use all the checkboxes and then in the post I want to check if any of the checkboxes was checked (true). Sorry for being a bugger but cant seem to get this done

Comment: There is not much point me repeating what I have already told you. If you claiming that when you select say the 'True' option in the dropdownlist and its not binding in the POST method, then its due to something you have not shown us. (and why are you saying _check if any of the checkboxes was checked_? (the code will NOT generate a checkbox - it generates a dropdownlist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments above, You cannot use `CheckBoxFor()` on a `bool?` What I would suggest is to change your model class to;

```
public partial class Role
{
    public int Role_Id { get; set; }
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public bool Door_Unlock { get; set; }
    public bool Accounts { get; set; }
    public bool Bounds_Email { get; set; }
    public bool Salary_Privilege { get; set; }
    public bool Card_Acceptance { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

and your controller remains the same;

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EmpID,Door_Unlock,Accounts,Bounds_Email,Salary_Privilege,Card_Acceptance,IsAdmin")] Role roles)
        {
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    //db.Roles.Add(roles);
                   // db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
```

and your Create.cshtml;

```
@model granjurEPS.Models.Role

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Role";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New User Role</h2>
@*@using (Html.BeginForm())*@
<form method="POST">


    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName, "Select Employee", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EnrollNumber", null, "-Select Employee-", htmlAttributes: new { id = "ddEnrollNumber", @class = "form-control" })


            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Accounts, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor( model => model.Accounts, new { name = "accountsCheck", @class = "accountsCheck" })
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Accounts.Value)*@

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Accounts, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bounds_Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Bounds_Email, new { @class = "boundsCheck" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bounds_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Card_Acceptance, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Card_Acceptance, new { @class = "cardCheck" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Card_Acceptance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Door_Unlock, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Door_Unlock, new { @class = "doorUnlockCheck" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Door_Unlock, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary_Privilege, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Salary_Privilege, new { @class = "salaryCheck" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salary_Privilege, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsAdmin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsAdmin, new { @class = "isAdminCheck" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsAdmin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Grant Permissions" class="btn green" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>


<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn green">  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @style = "color:#FFFFFF;" }) <span class=""></span></button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working in ASP.Net can be confusing for a simple reason:

No mater how much it might **look** like a Desktop application, it is still a 1980 HTML WebFormular. All the old rules and design decisions are still there.

The Commentors are trying to tell you something like this:

If you leave the creation/mapping of your BackgroundClasses to HTML to some automatic, you can not use nullable bools. The HTML Checkbox does not have 3-state support. It comes from a time, when 3 state support was not yet a thing. It is a simple old 2 State Checkbox. It shares that property with the old [Windows Forms Checkbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked.aspx).

The closest HTML mapping if you have 3+ states is a Dropdown list. So either:

- stop using nullable bools
- stop trying to use a checkbox